# Results of making a call on ADB

Tags: android, adb, at-command

In the documentation of AT command for CDMA, I find that when we start a call with ATD123456789, there is differents response. There is a response: "WCNT:9 the caller can hear audio of the calling party's phone ringing. However this event does not means the other calling party has answered".
When a trying to send the ATD123456789 from adb on my Android  phone, they make me:

```
 ATD123456789;
 OK
```

but not the response WCNT:9.
Some one can help me, why WCNT:9 don't display. And if there is another solution to detect the time of playing audio of the calling party's phone ringing.
Thank you and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

you can do `dumpsys telephony.registry` and check the `mCallState` value

```
CALL_STATE_IDLE = 0
CALL_STATE_RINGING = 1
CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK = 2
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not what I searched; my question is about outgoing call, not for incomming call. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the AT Interface then another command to consider is:

`AT+CLCC` List current calls

See [3GPP TS-27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/27_series/27.007/27007-8f0.zip)

The output should be simple to understand and gives you the following states:

```
<stat> (state of the call):
0   active
1   held
2   dialing (MO call)
3   alerting (MO call)
4   incoming (MT call)
5   waiting (MT call)
```